# What is the rule(s) to create controllers inside a src/ folder in Zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have created a module like:

```
module/
    Album/
        config/
        src/
            Album/
                Controller/
                    IndexController.php
        view/
```

Is there a only place to create controllers inside module under src/Album/Controller in **ZF2**?

I want to create  Controller(s) related to my module(Album) for Administrative tasks under src/ like

`module/Album/src/Admin/Controller/AdminController.php`

Is it possible? If it is possible how can I add routing  from module.config.php.

Please advise me. Thanks in advance

Comment: All the default ZF2 implementation does is asking you to follow PSR-0. But ultimately you can place your files wherever you want to.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no any rule to name controllers** because you define controller for a route in module.config.php and then in controller plugin manager.

For example, you define a route:

```
return [
   'router' => [
       'routes' => [
          'Album' => [
              'type' => 'Segment',
              'options' => [
                  'route' => 'album',
                  'defaults' => [
                      'controller' => 'album'
                  ]
              ]
          ]
       ]
   ]
];
```

Now, define the controller under the `controllers` key in module.config.php.

```
return [
   'controllers' => [
       'invokables' => [
            'album' => 'Album/Controller/AlbumController'
        ],
        'factories' => [
             // you do not need this. It is a advanced concept
        ]
    ]
];
```

**For Administrative purpose:**

For Administrative purpose, you can do however you are comfortable with. What I normally do is something like `Album\Controller\Backend\AlbumController`

Answer (score 0):

Ideed, the most common pratice is to place your controller under `module/Album/src/Admin/Controller/AdminController.php`.

And for declaring this controller, the best pratique is to use the module namespace, so it is easily identified in your code :

```
return [
   'controllers' => [
       'invokables' => [
            'Admin/Controller/Admin' => 'Admin/Controller/AdminController',
        ],
    ]
];
```

In your case, AdminController seems to be the default controller for Admin module, so maybe you could rename it to IndexController, as it is a common name for default controllers:

```
return [
       'controllers' => [
           'invokables' => [
                'Admin/Controller/Index' => 'Admin/Controller/IndexController',
            ],
        ]
    ];
```